# Change Azure directory from command line

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, az

I'm trying to use `az` against my Azure account. My account has two directories: one for personal (default) and one for business. I need to "switch to" the business directory so that `az` has access to the correct resources. However, I cannot find any way to achieve this via the command line, so when I do `az group list` I see the resource groups from my personal directory, not the business one.

How can I switch Azure directory from the CLI?

Answer (score 57):

Subscription and directory is not the same. You can have access to several subscriptions in your work directory for example.

To login to a different (non-default) directory, use the `--tenant` option with the `az login` command, passing the FQDN for the directory, e.g.

```
az login --tenant yourdir.onmicrosoft.com
```

You can find the FQDN in Azure Portal when listing the directories.

When logged into a directory, you can see list of all your available subscriptions.

[image: List of Directories in Azure Portal]

Comment: Also note you may need to add param `--allow-no-subscriptions` in case there is no subscription for the directory. So use like this: `az login --tenant yourdir.onmicrosoft.com --allow-no-subscriptions`. E.g. we have directory for Azure AD B2C created and seems to require this, but not sure why.

Comment: just wanted to say that the above comment saved me :)   thanks to both of you!

Comment: How should exactly do that for Azure Sign in VS code for Azure Resources

Answer (score 7):

```
# List of the tenants:
az account tenant list
[
  {
    "id": "/tenants/91358f27-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "tenantId": "91358f27-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "id": "/tenants/cf39b7bf-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "tenantId": "cf39b7bf-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
]

# Select the tenant ID:
az login --tenant cf39b7bf-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx --allow-no-subscriptions

# Set a validated subscription:
az account set --subscription "Pago por uso"

# Verify
az account list -o table
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, nevermind. For some reason the CLI calls them subscriptions when the portal calls them directories. So I needed `az account set --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID`

Comment: This way you only change the active subscription in your default directory. You need to specify the directory during `az login` as shown in my answer.