# Switch tenants from the command line using Microsoft Azure with 2FA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I'm trying to switch tenants from the command line interface on my Windows 10 computer.

The answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330786/change-azure-directory-from-command-line) don't seem to work at all

I've also tried the following

```
az logout 
az login --use-device-code (because of 2FA) 
az login --username [my user name] -t [tenant id] 
az login --tenant [tenant id] 
az login --tenant [tenant name] 
az account set --subscription [subscription id]
```

All these commands are completed successfully, however, when I run `Get-AzSubscription` command, I still see the tenentID of a different tenant I use than the one I want to log into.

How can one successfully switch tenants from the command line interface using Microsoft Azure with 2FA while developing cloud native apps on a Windows 10 PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Get-AzSubscription` to get the subscription information.

`Get-AzSubscription` is in Az.Accounts Powershell module.

But `az login` is in Azure CLI module. Switching tenants using `az login` doesn't effect on the results of `Get-AzSubscription`.

You can see the tenant information immediately after logging in using `az login --allow-no-subscriptions --tenant xxxx.onmicrosoft.com`.

You can also use [`az account show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_account_show) to get the details of a subscription and the tenant information.

Comment: Seems right. What does `--allow-no-subscriptions`  option do here?

Comment: You'd think that both the CLI and Powershell commands would communicate with the same API to GET results. I'm quite surprised that it doesn't work that way

Comment: @goonerify If we don't set `--allow-no-subscriptions`, it won't switch to a tenant that doesn't have any subscriptions.